# How to use Transformation Matrix for SpriteBatch correctly?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, xna, 2d, transformation

I'm new to XNA and would like to develop a light-weight 2D engine over it, with the entities organized into parent-child hierarchy. I think of matrix when drawing children, because their position, rotation and scale are depend on their parent.

If I use `SpriteBatch.Begin()`, my rectangles can be drawn on the screen, but when I change them into:

```
        this.DrawingMatrix = Matrix.Identity;
        this.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullClockwise, null, this.DrawingMatrix);
```

nothing is drawn anymore. I even tried `new Matrix()` or `Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0)` for `DrawingMatrix`.

My first question is: why doesn't it work? I'm not working with any camera or viewport.

Secondly, before drawing an entity, I call the `PreDraw` to transform the matrix (I will then reset to original state at `PostDraw`):

```
    protected virtual void PreDraw(Engine pEngine)
    {
        pEngine.DrawingMatrix *=
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(this.X, this.Y, 0) *
            Matrix.CreateScale(this.ScaleX, this.ScaleY, 1) *
            Matrix.CreateRotationZ(this.Rotation);
    }
```

Please clarify the correction of above code. And I need to scale not at the origin, but at `ScaleCenterX` and `ScaleCenterY`, how can I achieve this?

**ADDED**: Here is an example of my engine's draw process:

1. Call these code:

   ```
       this.DrawingMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0);
       this.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullClockwise, null, this.DrawingMatrix);
   ```
2. Call `PreDraw()`, with is:

   ```
   protected virtual void PreDraw(Engine pEngine)
   {
       pEngine.DrawingMatrix *=
           Matrix.CreateTranslation(this.X, this.Y, 0) *
           Matrix.CreateScale(this.ScaleX, this.ScaleY, 1) *
           Matrix.CreateRotationZ(this.Rotation);
   }
   ```
3. Call `Draw()`, for example, in my `Rect` class:

   ```
   protected override void Draw(Engine pEngine)
   {
       pEngine.SpriteBatch.Draw(pEngine.RectangleTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)this.Width, (int)this.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1), this.Color);
   }
   ```

If I replace above `Begin` code with `this.SpriteBatch.Begin()`, the rectangle is drawn correctly, so I guess it is because of the matrix.

Comment: Using Matrix.Identity should result in the same behavior as not specifying a matrix at all, so I don't think that's your problem.  Can you post some of the code that's actually responsible for drawing your sprites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First issue is a simple bug: The default for `SpriteBatch` is `CullCounterClockwise`, but you have specified `CullClockwise` causing all your sprites to get back-face-culled. You can pass `null` if you just want to use the default render states - you don't need to specify them explicitly.

(You would need to change the cull mode if you used a negative scale.)

To answer your second question: You need to translate "back" to place the scaling origin (your `ScaleCenterX` and `ScaleCenterY`) at the world origin (0,0). Transformations always happen around (0,0). So normally the order is: translate sprite origin back to the world origin, scale, rotate, translate to place sprite origin at desired world position.

Also, I hope that your `PostDraw` is not applying the reverse transformations (you made it sound like it does). That is very likely to cause precision problems. You should save and restore the matrix instead.

Comment: Good catch on the cull mode, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I meet another problem. I look like the `Matrix` in XNA is immutable, and everytime I modify, a new instance is created, so I have to keep calling `Begin()` and `End()` for each `Entity`. Is it a good practice? Is there a better way to modify existing Matrix?

Comment: `Matrix` is a value type (a mutable one). So whenever you pass it around - such as in an argument to `Begin` - it is copied. If you modify the original, the copy does not see the changes. The matrix is used as a shader parameter - which means it must be per-batch. Batches have a cost (see [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9289/288) for details). If this causes you to draw enough batches to hit the batch limit, you may need to implement an alternate drawing method. The maths required to "stack" the parameters to `Draw` isn't too hard to figure out - probably the easiest way.

Comment: Oh, what do you mean `stack` the parameters?

Comment: @W.N. I'm having a mind-blank trying to think of the appropriate term. But basically when one element of your hierarchy has a transform, and then a child has another transform. When you draw the child, both transforms are applied, the parent's first. As I mentioned - you should save and restore the transformation as you traverse the scene graph - and the appropriate data structure for storing the transforms during traversal is a *stack*. While matrices are one way to store the transform - it is possible (but more complex) to store them as rotate/scale/translate which can be used by `Draw`.